# In react <Option> selected default value is not getting selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux, dropdown

When I click the first option, it doesn't take the first option. After clicking some other option, then I click first option, it then takes the value

```
Fruits.map((x, index) => { return <Option selected={myFruit.name === x.name} value={index}>{x.name}</Option>
```

Comment: this should work : {myFruit.name === x.name ? 'selected' : ''}

Answer (score 0):

Use your state value in the `select` element instead of `selected` in the option

```
<select value={myFruit.name}>
// options
</select>
```